# What is the purpose of using negation before function declaration?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap source code I found the following:

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;
```

I've never met such a construction before. What does it mean? It looks like IIFE, but I am not sure it is the equivalent.

Comment: I guess negation is used to convert the statement to expression, right? But why not using parentheses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns it into an expression, usually followed by `()`. It saves a byte over using parentheses, at the cost of wasting about a hundred StackOverflow questions.

Comment: So don't waste it, but close it.